# Splitting a character into different cells without a delimiter

Tags: google-sheets-api

everyone

I would like to know how to split something like }{ )( ++ ** into 2 different cells in excel/google sheets i tried using the split function in google sheets but it requires a delimiter, i was successful in using excel's split to column toolbox but google sheets (I cant find one, it asks fore either a space , | etc or custom) but i cant be ""

data tab >  text to column> fixed width > data columns
click on the arrow
and make the lines even by columns

works, question is how do i do that in google sheets?

Answer (score 0):

You may try using the sample formula if you have a common pattern as given in [Google Docs Forum](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/docs/zLCLZJgzEe8/mj6WpdYFBwAJ).

However, as discussed in [Combining and Splitting Data in Spreadsheets](https://sites.google.com/a/slu.edu/tips/home/combiningandsplittingdatainspreadsheets), delimiter is a character upon which you will split the contents of the Spreadsheets cell and using it is still required.

With reference to the given example:

> if you want to split the text contained in the column A, using the delimiter " " (space), we will first need to insert an extra column. **This will insure the formula doesn’t replace what is currently in column B**.

Comment: REGEXEXTRACT(A20,"(.+?)\s*(.+?)\s*(.+?)\s*(.+?)")

i used this idea to split it but its not so elegant, is there a way to do it for flags, without splitting the flags characters such the australia flag which is AU <- 2 characters, this way i did splits them apart and the flag no longer shows up? can you help me?